# code coverage of Javascript in war (running under tomcat)

Tags: javascript, code-coverage

I have web application running under tomcat. In web application, lots of unused javascript code is present. When I run web application, I want to find unused code using code coverage of Javascripts. After googling, I don't find single example for same purpose. Can any one suggest link or example and tool which does the same ? Please note, javascript is part of webapplication (war file) and I want code coverage for it.

Comment: why the question been -ve. what is wrong in question ?

Answer (score 1):

I found jscoverage tool for js code coverage resided in war file. It's important to note that, it does not matter where your js file resides, jscoverage will instrument code.

Follow below steps.

1. Download jscoverage from http://siliconforks.com/jscoverage/download.html.
2. Goto inside the folder where jscoverage.exe resides.
3. Use command jscoverage
4. Replace js folder with newly instrumented . P.N. JS file is part of .war file so you can replace js folder with newly instrumented js folder.
5. http://localhost:8080/context/js/jscoverage.html (Path will vary as per your context name.

That's it !!